# Как понять принцип работы return в примере кода?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Добрый день господа.
Есть вот такой код в примерах на данном хабе https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core

```
ytdl(url, { 
  filter: function(format) { 
    return format.container === 'mp4'; 
  } 
})  
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('vide.mp4'));
```

Мне не понятен принцип работы `return format.container === 'mp4';` 
Я пытался сам проверить что к чему, сделал forEach, for, обычный if с таким условием, но не понятно что происходит в данном return, будьте добры, объясните пожалуйста, или скажите как это называется вообще, а то гуглануть правильно не могу.

Comment: return возвращает результат ... А === дает истину если значение полностью такое или ложь в остальных случаях. В итоге return возвращает вычисленное значение, true или false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша библиотека скачивает видео с YouTube. Видео загружаются в разном формате, иногда вам нужно скачать видео если оно имеет определенное расширение. Если формат скачиваемого видео mp4 то выражение вида:

```
return format.container === 'mp4';
```

вернет `true` это и будет являться признаком того что видео нужного расширения. В этом случае это работает как стандартная функция [filter](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration#filter) для массивов.